# Javascript redirect to specific path in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

how can I redirect to specific url that appear in the url parameter?

for example:

http://www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/redir.html?path=

After the "=" I will add the specific URL I want redirect to.

The result URL will eventually look like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/redir.html?path=http://www.newwebsite.com/

the javascript redirect in redir.html need to copy the 'path' url and redirect the page to there.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the querystring javascript function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values):

```
window.location.href = getParameterByName("path");

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: still not work for me... for example: http://www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/redir.html?path=http://www.google.com/ not redirect me to google.

Answer (score 0):

javascript function to get query parameter:

```
function get_query_param(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

window.onload = function() {
    if (get_query_param('path') != null) 
        alert(get_query_param('path'));
}
```

hope that helped